# Shortest Path between two matrices

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, matrix, networkx

I have two distance matrices with overlapping variable names.

dfA:

```
    Start   A1  A2  A3  A4  … A150
Location                        
A           12  4   12  2      9
B           5   2   19  4      3
C           1   4   8   7      12
```

dfB:

```
    A   B   C           
X   4   12  32          
Y   1   6   12          
Z   2   8,5 11
```

So from start A1, A2, etc. through ABC there are paths to X, Y and Z

I would like to see what is the shortest path for an item, for example the the combination A1 -> Z. I programmed this by loading csv's with the distance matrices and unstack them. Then with df.itterows() and two for loops loop through the possible combinations and see what the smallest is for the combination A1 -> Z.

But since i have to do this for around 30000 items, it takes way to long.

Anybody know how to do this in a vectorized way?

Comment: Added networkx tag, might be helpful for such path related problems.

Comment: Ah i forgot it, thanks!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that this just takes 2 steps?  It's never good to go A1 to B to A3 to C to X?

Comment: it really seems then like it's: "add column of first matrix to corresponding row of second matrix and find minimum element"  numpy has ways to do all of these (but I'm not an expert so I'd have to use google to figure it out).

Comment: btw - when you've posted a question, you'll get a notice about any comments.  However, no-one else will get a notice.  If you are responding to someone's question, it's useful to do @username at the start of your comment.  Then they get an alert.

Comment: why is there a `8,5` value in `dfB` (row `Z`, col `B`)?

Comment: It takes 8,5 minutes from Z to B. I know, this implicates floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `D` so that the axis lengths will be different (`dfB` won't be square matrix) just for my convenience (it works with square matrices too).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_a = pd.read_csv('dfA.csv', delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, decimal=",")
df_b = pd.read_csv('dfB.csv', delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, decimal=",")
mat_a = df_a.values
mat_b = df_b.values
mat_a2 = np.expand_dims(mat_a, axis=2)
mat_b2 = np.expand_dims(mat_b.T, axis=1)
mat_a3 = np.tile(mat_a2, (1, 1, mat_b.shape[0]))
mat_b3 = np.tile(mat_b2, (1, mat_a.shape[1], 1))
tot = mat_a3 + mat_b3
ind = np.argmin(tot, axis=0).T
df_c = pd.DataFrame(df_b.columns.values[ind], columns=df_a.columns, index=df_b.index)
print(df_c)
```

dfA:

```
Start_Location   A1  A2  A3  A4  A150
A                12  4   12  2      9
B                5   2   19  4      3
C                1   4   8   7      12
D                5   2   9   11     4
```

dfB:

```
    A   B   C   D
X   4   12  32  11,4
Y   1   6   2  9,3
Z   2   8,5 11  1,4
```

dfC:

```
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A150
X  A  A  A  A    A
Y  C  A  C  A    B
Z  D  D  D  A    D
```